# PSU Unit for 4 Raspberry Pi 4 B with 8gb ram

Tags: pi-4

Hi Raspberry Pi Stackexchange,
Im am considering to build my own small server at home with 4 clustered raspberry pi 4. I have been looking for an adequate PSU but haven't found anything that suits the requirements. I have read some forum pages but I haven't found anything really helpfull that I could use.

If I understood the PSU requirements correctly it has to have at least 60W at 3A to power four of the pi 4. Is that correct? If that's the case ist this PSU suitable for the setup? https://www.amazon.de/-/en/InLine%C2%AE-Charge-Notebook-Supply-Charger/dp/B07MN3NNQG

I'd rather ask before I damage the rather expensive setup.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The suggested power supply voltage for all Pis is 5.1 volts.

The recommended PSU current for the Pi4B is 3 amps (although bare-board usage may be as little as 0.6 amps).

See [Power Supply](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/power/)

For the recommended current you will need 5.1 * 3 * 4 or 61.2 watts.

Personally I'd just buy a bog standard PC power supply.

You can easily find one which supplies more than enough power at 5 volts.